# Feature or tag to request assistance from non native English speakers?

Tags: support, feature-request, languages, english

On the C and C++ tagged questions on Stack Overflow, I notice a large number of questions that are closed due to low quality. A fraction of them, let's say 20%, seem to be attempts at forming a good question, but are severely impeded by a language barrier. While I think Stack Overflow should make a habit of keeping all the content in a single common language (i.e. English), I think there would be some benefit to having a way to draw attention to a technical problem which is adversely impacted by a language barrier.

Does anyone else feel there may be tag or feature that would be worth implementing where attention can be drawn to a question such that a multi-lingual Stack Overflow user could address the poster's questions in a language other than English in a chat section or the comments section of a question, then post the final accepted answer in English?

I think an entirely new feature might be overkill, but maybe a tag (something more appropriate than "Engrish" I'd assume) could be used, or maybe a language-specific tag (ie: Language:Cantonese, Language:Italian, etc) to help out non-native English speakers? Those of us on Stack Overflow that are multi-lingual could add the tag or maybe a compound tag (ie: in my case, `C && Language:Italian`) and help out when a question is being flagged for closure when it might still be a good question.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Tags for this are a no-go. We really don't want meta-tags on SO questions.

Comment: I was just suggesting pretty much the same thing on another question; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354265/1832568 Good job! :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Support for people who don't speak English is certainly a great idea. **However, I don't think it should be done on the general Stack Overflow**. Language barriers are a big issue - let's keep one language per website. Meta-tags aren't a great solution either. Multiple languages on one site poses big issues for how the system works - would we need moderators for each language, like a Russian moderator or a Spanish moderator? How would reviews work if some of the posts being reviewed wouldn't be in your language? Overall, it just isn't a very practical solution.

However, you'll be happy to know that this issue is already being addressed by the StackExchange team. As mentioned in the recent [2014 Year Review Stack Exchange blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/year-in-review-2014/),

> We launched Portuguese and Japanese Stack Overflows, our first non-English SOs.  Portuguese is now officially our second fastest-growing community ever after hitting 10,000 questions in only 9 months.

Though you probably won't be able to read them, you should check them out for yourself ([here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) and [here](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)). They are doing very well.

The reason that there aren't more is, if I remember correctly from other posts I've seen around, porting a site to a different language has a lot of hidden technical issues behind the scenes, so it's taking them some time to build a clean and efficient system to create sites for more languages. However, I think that they'll be adding more languages fairly quickly as the translation process becomes easier.

Comment: Just considering the need for multi-language moderation alone points out a major flaw in my approach. Also, thanks for the heads-up on those other SO sites.