# Should SO users be actively encouraged to be more patient where cultural misunderstandings are evident?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, etiquette, behavior

Coders from all over the world use Stack Overflow for and to help understanding this vast subject.

I don't have statistics to hand, but in my experience, a large number of users are clearly not native English speakers, but seem expected to post as if they are, with frequently impatient and even aggressive responses to less than perfect posts.

I understand that there are several localized versions of SO for users of different (spoken) languages, but that these are:

1. Less well known and frequented.
2. Not obviously necessary to a user who considers their English language skills good enough to post *here*.

Alongside the language barrier, there are less well understood differences in **cultural etiquette**, which when combined with a less than perfect grasp of English, can result in destructive confusion.

A couple of references outlining this problem can be seen in:

1. This [simple introductory slideshare](https://www.slideshare.net/ajbessette/cultural-misunderstanding-13464252).
2. This [more scholarly .pdf from the Canadian Center of Science and Education](http://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/ass/article/viewFile/2492/2338).

There are of course many other resources and studies out there, but these should suffice to frame the scope of this discussion.

I was pleased to find these questions (with answers) on meta, demonstrating an awareness of the issue:

1. [What to do when a language barrier makes a post unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260994/what-to-do-when-a-language-barrier-makes-a-post-unclear)

   - [An answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261041/1832568)
2. [Show a dialog asking users to be more specific if they use the phrase "didn't work" in a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349085/show-a-dialog-asking-users-to-be-more-specific-if-they-use-the-phrase-didnt-wo)

   - [An answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349094/1832568)

Excerpts:

> ...such a situation demands a little more patience with the user to give him the opportunity to clarify. If it is just a language barrier (and not an unwillingness to cooperate for example) a little patience can result in a great question or answer. Language problems tend to be temporary and resolvable

And:

> People asking a hazy "didn't work" question is sometimes indeed down to a cultural misunderstanding rather than laziness. People (mostly non-technical ones) often confuse online media with how normal human conversations tend to work.
>
> In a conversation, it is normal to start with something vague like "Hey, why does this thing not work?"

However, these posts are more focussed on the technical procedure of handling unclear posts.

**I believe it would be beneficial to actively encourage SO users to exercise patience and offer constructive guidance when handling unclear posts by users with obvious linguistic and/or cultural difficulties.**

---

An example of just one recent question that suffered from linguistic and cultural misunderstanding can be seen at:

- [How to randomly generate two colors with a slight difference in shade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437511/how-to-randomly-generate-two-colors-with-a-slight-difference-in-shade)

As is typical, [the first published draft](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45437511/1) was swiftly downvoted, and commentary was added suggesting improvement be made.

Unfortunately, another comment suggested the user was being abrupt and demanding, quoting the OP's

> Ignore the rest coding just provide the random JS functions

This sentence is obviously not well formed, and although a culturally native English speaker would rightly be considered *rude*, the meaning *should be* clear enough.

The downvotes piled up quickly, **whilst the OP [edited in positive response](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45437511/4) to feedback**.

[Negativity bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_bias), having already (within minutes) kicked this poor question while it's down, continued as I stepped in to attempt clarification by comment and editing.

I felt I had a good enough understanding of the OP's problem to post an answer, and went ahead.

I later discovered that the question had been put on hold as "[too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)" not long afterwards.

> too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format

It is my opinion that this hold is more a result of the initial misunderstanding of the question, than fair in relation to the actual content or intent of the question (once improved).

I have edited again in the hope of having the hold lifted, but - we'll see.

---

So that is just one example of how poor (spoken) language skills, and (not necessarily therefore) cultural misunderstanding can crush a perfectly reasonable question (or answer).

I'd like finally to make clear that the above example is not the focus of this post, but rather that the communication difficulties we often face can if acted upon rashly, cause users to lose out.

And with that in mind, I wonder if we can adopt a culture of more patient assistance for users who are simply trying their best?

Comment: *"I believe it would be beneficial to actively encourage SO users to exercise patience... and/or cultural difficulties."* - On this point I have this to say; it does happen that the language barrier is just that, a barrier to which can be hard to overcome. The only real solution here, would be to know what their native language is and for a person that can communicate with them, edit their post accordingly. However, it can happen that they comment/answer in their language and get flagged because of it. We shouldn't have to paste that in a translator, and things can get lost in translation.

Comment: You really should find better example...Question starting from no-effort / no research shown is not a good example of "cultural misunderstanding" (unless I'm misunderstanding your post altogether). Is your actual question is "how to make people read directions to ask better questions"? Note that answering questions that have plenty of duplicates (judging by "related" to question you talking about) is not a good example of answering either...

Comment: No @AlexeiLevenkov, _"how to make people read directions to ask better questions?"_ is not my question. And as stated, the example is just that; let's not focus on **it**.

Comment: *"The downvotes piled up quickly, whilst the OP edited in positive response to feedback."* - Well, that wasn't a "cultural" thing, as it was  tagged as "php" to which there was no code to support the question. Some of the members who voted to close the question, are (known) php coders where they may have expected to see some php; alas there wasn't. When there is no supportive code, that makes it both unclear and too broad. Often times, questions are not well tagged. Had I seen that question because I do look at that thread, I'd of posted a comment asking for relevance for the (php) tag.

Comment: The above comment is in relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45437511/1415724).

Comment: I admit @Fred-ii-, that I did not notice the tag issue, and can imagine users being frustrated by it; I'm sure it played a contributory part. The tag should be removed, but whilst the edited post is hopefully queued for review, that should perhaps wait until a decision is made?

Comment: @FredGandt I'd bet my bottom dollar that that was the underlying issue. I have removed the php tag from it in [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45437511/8).

Comment: @FredGandt Either what I said above, and/or because [their original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45437511/1) did not contain any code. It started off as a *"How to"* and that was a "first impression". I hope that they will learn from this experience. The OP probably posted their code after seeing [John's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437511/how-to-randomly-generate-two-colors-with-a-slight-difference-in-shade#comment77835854_45437511). Often, most ignore messages asking them to post their code etc. etc. I see this all too often ;-)

Comment: @FredGandt I'm confused what "cultural misunderstanding" you are talking about than. If post contains just "need {*something*}. give me teh codez" it will be downvoted/closed even if it is written in perfect English. If such post is shows what user can do "trying their best" then there is not much can be done on SO to help. I understand that *you* want to show research (which is always welcome), but it is hard to see problem you want to talk about with given example - and it should be relatively easy to find better one *if indeed it is a common problem*.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I grew up in a town which hosted 10's of 1000's of _foriegn_ language students every year, and was accustomed to hearing _"Give me"_ instead of _"May I have"_ or _"I want"_ instead of _"I would like"_. The students were _"trying their best"_, converting what is considered perfectly proper in their own culture, to the best English they could muster. I acknowledge that the example's OP's first draft sucked, but the request for more info should require patience and understanding to follow. I actually thought of a possible solution whilst walking my dog, and will post as answer.

Comment: I would be happy to help with a question phrased badly, but with the code, inputs and outputs and error messages copypasta'd in.  An explanation in broken/mangled English of what was found during testing/debugging would be great!  'Donnezz lez codezzz' I will close vote in any form.

Answer (score -15):

If it can be agreed that there is a problem of cultural and/or linguistic communication difficulties standing between users and assistance, a simple solution could be applied.

Were a button (we like buttons - clicky, clicky!) to be deployed, attached to every post (questions and answers) from the moment they start to form, that when clicked would mark the post as being submitted in English by a non-fluent speaker, we could quickly, and easily see that a little more patience and understanding should be exhibited.

This functionality would **never** be an excuse for a lack of quality, but rather, an indicator of a specific issue the post has that affects its early life, and how it can best be developed.

The button could be used by the OPs or by any editor (perhaps with a certain privilege) who had good reason to think and assume it should be marked.

A visual indicator could prominently show that the post's language and structure may for this very specific reason be in need of editorial oversight.

Any users who felt they didn't have time to deal with a question they might find difficult to unravel, could quickly filter against it and move on to other posts, whilst those with a bounty of patience could spend time helping the OP to develop the post.

Everyone wins.

I would suggest that although this sounds a lot like adding a tag, it should not be muddled in with the current tagging system.

Comment: [Handling questions from non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291177) | [Feature or tag to request assistance from non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283204) | [Is it OK to downvote questions because of bad grammar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253780)